# Alternative to raising Http404 from within a function call, (Django FormView)?

Tags: django, exception, httpresponse

I have a FormView which renders a ModelForm in the template. The form includes ModelChoiceField based on a dynamic queryset that is passed in the kwargs when the form is initialised (see full code for the view below)

```
 def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    """ Provides keyword arguemnt """

    kwargs = super(NameofView, self).get_form_kwargs()

    queryset = self.my_custom_method(self.param1, self.param2)
    kwargs.update({"queryset": queryset})

    return kwargs
```

This queryset is determined by an initial database query **using values from the session**, and filtered further. There are quite a few methods in play before arriving at the one above, so that the same queryset is formed in both request.POST and request.GET.

Specifically, I call a method:

```
 def get_initial_queryset(self, session_variable1, session_variable2):
     
    initial_queryset = Model.objects.filter(
        attr1=session_variable1
    ).filter(
        attr2__gte=session_variable2)
    
    if not initial_queryset:
        raise Http404("Sorry, none available")
    return initial_queryset
```

I am considering a situation where this initial query returns no results. The methods that follow would raise errors and ultimately the form would not be rendered and it would be quite a catastrophe!!

Therefore I would need to break out of the flow somehow and instead render a message that says something like 'Sorry nothing was found'.

As you can see, I currently have `if not initial_queryset: raise Http404()` but I am not satisfied with this solution as technically it's not a 'page not found' and would need a custom message for this scenario.

I would prefer to redirect the user to another view and render a message with links to go back edit their search (for example.)

I have tried returning `HttpResponseRedirect()` but that just assigns the Response object to the variable that called the function!

Is there a better way to acheive this?

```
class NameofView(FormView):


model = Model
template_name = "app/template.html"
form_class = RefineSelectionForm

def get_initial_queryset(self, session_variable1, session_variable2):
    initial_queryset = Model.objects.filter(
        attr1=session_var1
    ).filter(
        attr2__gte=session_var2)
    if not initial_queryset:
        raise Http404("Sorry, none available")
    return initial_queryset

def refine_queryset1(self, session_var1, session_var2, session_var3):
    initial_queryset = self.get_initial_queryset(session_var1, session_var2)
    refined_qs1 = initial_queryset.filter(session_var1__gte=session_var1)[:3]
    return refined_qs1

def refine_queryset2(self, self, session_var1, session_var2, session_var3):
    initial_queryset = self.get_intitial_queryset(session_var1, session_var2)
    refined_qs2 = initial_queryset.filter(attr__lt=date).order_by("-date")[:3]
    return refined_qs2

def my_custom_method(self, param1, param2):
    """Creates the queryset that will be used by the ModelChoiceField
    in the Form"""

    # Merge both queries
    queryset = param1 | param2
    return queryset

def get_initial(self):
    # Retrieve values from the session
    session_variable1 = self.request.session["session_variable1"]
    self.session_variable2 = self.request.session["session_variable2"]
    self.session_variable3 = self.request.session["session_variable3"]

    ..comparisons etc...

    if condition:
        initial_data = initial_data1
    else:
        initial_data = initial_data2

    initial = super(NameofView, self).get_initial()
    initial.update({"formfield": initial_data})
    return initial

def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(NameofView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    queryset = self.my_custom_method(self.param1, self.param2)
    kwargs.update({"queryset": queryset})
    return kwargs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(NameofView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)       
    queryobject = Model.objects.filter(pk=self.session_variable1)
    context["some_data"] = self.session_variable2
    context["some_object"] = queryobject
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    ...code...
    return redirect("named_path", args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override the `get` function to perform the basic validation before even getting to the form logic.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    if not self.get_available_trips().exists():
        return render(request, "some_unavailable_template", context={"message": "your message"})
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

As you have found out, a redirect doesn't allow you to customize the message. If you're set on a redirect, you could redirect to another view that goes through the same logic to determine why the trips are unavailable, then present a message. You could probably pull out some of the common functions into a view mixin.

Comment: You can use `django.contrib.messages` to set a message before redirecting.

Comment: How do I redirect out of the function though? I am assigning the result of the function to a variable so any return statement I put is just returning that value, even if it is a HttpResponseRedirect object!

Comment: @schilllingt. I think that will work. Thank you